# Proof of irrationality of $\zeta(2)$ without explicitly calculating it

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Question is pretty much the title. It is pretty easy to show that $\zeta(2n)$ is irrational for all $n$ once you know that $\zeta(2n)$ is a rational multiple of $\pi^{2n}$ (and then also use the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental or some other related result). My question is, does anyone know of a proof that $\zeta(2)$ is irrational without evaluating it as $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and using the fact that $\pi^2$ is irrational? Perhaps one that uses its series definition or integral representations?

Not homework, just curious.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30659/establishing-zeta3-as-a-definite-integral-and-its-computation/30784#30784 (referred to in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/202858/question-on-the-irrationality-of-e)

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} = \prod_p (1-p^{-2}) = \prod_p  \frac{p^2-1}{p^2} = \prod_p \frac{(p+1)(p-1)}{p^2}  = \prod_p \frac{4 \frac{p+1}{2}\frac{p-1}{2}}{p^2}$ which cannot be rational because ...

Comment: because the $\prod_p 4$ will never simplify with the denominators

Comment: @user1952009 Woah that was remarkably simple, and I think I understand it. If you would like to make that an answer and add details, then I will accept it.

Comment: @user1952009 Actually... that got me thinking... how do we know that a four being present in the numerator of each of the products implies that a four will be present in the numerator of the limit?

Comment: @ASKASK : work. (even Euler noticed that  so you should be able to do it too)

Comment: @user1952009 Care to give any details? Last I checked, Euler did not have the same definition of convergence as us and made plenty of non-rigorous proofs

Comment: @user1952009, $(4/5)(20/17)(68/65)(260/257)...=1$, so I'm afraid your argument doesn't work.

Comment: So, ASK, have you had a look at Beukers' proof?

Comment: Are you still here, ASK?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes I'm still here. Beukers proof is a bit advanced for me but I can see that it does still work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beukers proved $\zeta(2)$ irrational without using $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$. An exposition of his proof is [here](http://paramanands.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/irrationality-of-zeta-2-and-zeta-3-part-1.html#.VrVtRVIqZFI).